# Passing arrays between procedures

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I've searched here and the web for a solution, but they just seem to cause other errors I'm too inexperienced with (the first build was in PHP, now I have to move it to a stored procedure). What I have is a map of my campus, and when a user clicks on a building, an info bubble pops open to show some information and a gallery of pictures. The address of the picture are stored in a table, so I need them to come back in an array so I can loop through them. The call to get the list is:

```
$.ajax({ //get the picture URLs, load into array
        type: "post",
        url: "video_tour.get_pics",
        data: { pBldg_id:  building
        },
        error: function(xhr,thrownError) { alert("error get pics"); },
        success: function(data){
                  $.each(data, function(index,obj) {
                         picArray[index] = obj.ADDRESS;
                  });
        }
});//and ajax for pic load
```

and the called procedure:

```
procedure get_pics(pBldg_id int) is
     type array_varchar is table of varchar2(2000) index by binary_integer;

     array_of_pics array_varchar;
     v_counter int := 0;
begin

for i in(select address from ucs.campus_pictures where building_id = pBldg_id and thumbnail = 1) loop
     array_of_pics(v_counter) := i.address;
     v_counter := v_counter + 1;
end loop;               

end get_pics;
```

How can I can I take the array_of_pics back to the ajax call?

Comment: You'll probably need to change your get_pics procedure, as procedures do not return a value. You probably want a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it wasn't as complex as it seemed, I just need to print the data as it comes out and add a delimiting character:

```
  for i in(select address from ucs.campus_pictures where building_id = pBldg_id and thumbnail = 1) loop
htp.prn(i.address || ';');
end loop;
```

and make an array in the ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({ //get the picture URLs, load into array
                     type: "post",
                     url: "video_tour.get_pics",
                     data: { pBldg_id:  building
                     },
                     error: function(xhr,thrownError) { alert("error get pics"); }, 
                     success: function(data){
                      $.each(data.split(";"), function(index,obj) {
                                    picArray[index] = obj;
                              });

                     }
            });
```

Thanks guys for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have some middleware (even if its a PHP page) that handles the requests then invokes the procedure.  Starting there you actually want to return a cursor (see below example).  In your middleware, you'll loop over the result set coming from your cursor.

```
    create or replace function get_pics(bldg_id_in ucs.campus_pictures.building_id%TYPE)
return sys_refcursor
as
ref_cursor sys_refcursor;
begin
   open ref_cursor for
     select address from ucs.campus_pictures where building_id = bldg_id_in and thumbnail = 1;
   return ref_cursor;
end;
```

Comment: There isn't any underlying PHP code with this. The stored procedures print the html/javascript to the browser. I'm barely familiar with cursors, and I'll check this out when I'm there tomorrow - since it's jQuery calling the procedure, is a cursor what I want to return? or do i wan't to print the results from the cursor? How it's setup (I don't know if it's clear, is using stored procedures to write html normal?) is called procedures print whatever data the calling procedure needs for returned values. So I think I need it to come back in a form that is, or can be turned into, a JS array.

Comment: You wrote that the stored procedures print the HTML/JavaScript to teh borwser. Is it done using the HTP package?